# USB drive mount point bugs out

Tags: 14.04, usb-drive

I'm using several ext4 formatted USB drives (of different make) which have to be removed regularly **without any "safe unmounting"**.

Sometimes, and this appears to be completely random and may only happen once in hundreds of tries, the mount point (let's call it /media/username/usbmount) **would remain after removal and subsequently refuse to disappear**. If the USB drive is inserted again, a new mount point is created (e.g. /media/username/usbmount1).

Until I manually delete the old mount point and fix the whole thing, the problem does not disappear. This is not acceptable since the device running Ubuntu is sold to customers that cannot be expected to do this.

What can be the cause of this faulty mount behaviour? Are there ways to circumvent/fix it?